# Alternative to __del__ for final result & killing processes in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, garbage-collection, multiprocessing

This dummy class is similar to a current project of mine:

```
class EndProcess(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._Q = multiprocessing.Queue()

        self.p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=("p1",))
        self.p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=("p2",))
        self.p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=("p3",))
        self.p1.start()
        self.p2.start()
        self.p3.start()


    def worker(self, name):
        while True:
            rnd = random.randint(0, 100)
            self._Q.put((name, rnd))
            print(name, rnd)
            time.sleep(1)


    def __del__(self):
        # "log" final state of Queue
        while not self._Q.empty():
            print(self._Q.get())

        # free resources
        ...

        # clean up workers
        self.p1.terminate()
        self.p2.terminate()
        self.p3.terminate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ep = EndProcess()
```

The problem is that `__del__` is not guaranteed to be always called, especially at important points in time, since `__del__` is only called by Python's garbage collector when the reference count of the object reaches zero.

How can I assure that resources always get set free and the workers always get terminated?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the [_With Statement Context Managers_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers)?

Comment: So you suggest that I wrap the process creation and starting in a with-statement? Wouldn't this block my main process' `__init__` method?

Comment: No? If you create an instance of `EndProcess` before the `with` statement, and then do `with end_process_object as name:` that would seem to work to me. `__enter__` will be called when the `with` statement starts. And `__exit__` will be called when the `with` statement is exited, so you could put your clean-up work there.

Comment: Would you mind giving some example (some lines of code)? I guess I have misunderstood something about the context manager's concept...at least I can not figure out how to correctly implement your suggestion at the moment.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to give a quick answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I assure that resources always get set free and the workers always get terminated?

You can accomplish this by implementing the context manager methods [`__enter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__) and [`__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__). You can then use your `EndProcess` class with the context manger statement `with`. This way, your clean-up logic will executed even if an error occurs:

```
class EndProcess(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._Q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=("p1",))
        self.p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=("p2",))
        self.p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=("p3",))
        self.p1.start()
        self.p2.start()
        self.p3.start()

    def worker(self, name):
        while True:
            rnd = random.randint(0, 100)
            self._Q.put((name, rnd))
            print(name, rnd)
            time.sleep(1)

    def __enter__(self):
        # Add your setup logic here. Initialize any data structures.
        # set any threads, etc.
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        # The three arguments to `__exit__` describe the exception
        # caused the `with` statement execution to fail. If the `with`
        # statement finishes without an exception being raised, these
        # arguments will be `None`.
        #
        # These arguments may be useful for things such as logging, or 
        # debugging.
        while not self._Q.empty():
            print(self._Q.get())
        ...
        self.p1.terminate()
        self.p2.terminate()
        self.p3.terminate()
        ...
```

Now you can use `EndProcess` instances in a context manager statement:

```
end_process = EndProcess()
...
with end_process as ep:
    # Use ep like you would normally. `__enter__` and `__exit__` will be
    # automatically.
    pass
```