# How to wrap a context manager class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, with-statement, contextmanager

I have written a dummy class that manages some IO processes similar to a real project of mine. Since `__del__` is not guaranteed to be called (see: [Alternative to __del__ for final result & killing processes in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655448/alternative-to-del-for-final-result-killing-processes-in-a-class?noredirect=1#comment78269205_45655448)), I now use the suggested approach of context managers, which works fine.

However, there is one problem: what if somebody else "forgets" to use my class in a `with` statement? And what if I want to have several of these classes? This would end up in several `with`-encapsulations?!

That is why I wanted to wrap the `with`-statement within a wrapper class:

```
class EndProcessWrapper(object):

    @staticmethod
    def get_end_process():
        with EndProcessWrapper.EndProcess() as ep:
            return ep

    class EndProcess(object):

        def __init__(self):
            pass


        def worker(self, name):
            while True:
                rnd = random.randint(0, 100)
                self._Q.put((name, rnd))
                print(name, rnd)
                time.sleep(1)


        def __enter__(self):
            self._Q = multiprocessing.Queue()

            self.p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=("p1",))
            self.p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=("p2",))
            self.p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=("p3",))
            self.p1.start()
            self.p2.start()
            self.p3.start()

            return self


        def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, traceback):
            print("printing queue contents")
            while not self._Q.empty():
                print(self._Q.get())

            print("terminating processes")
            self.p1.terminate()
            self.p2.terminate()
            self.p3.terminate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ep = EndProcessWrapper.get_end_process()
    ...
    time.sleep(5)
```

This would allow for easy use and ensures that `EndProcess` is always used properly (inside a `with`-statement).

However, this does not work, because (obviously) `return ep` instantly returns the `EndProcess` object and therefore ends the with statement (resulting in calling `__exit__`).

Is there a pythonic way to wrap the `with`-statement?

Comment: In my personal opinion it is not going to be more pythonic when you wrap the wrapper. Also you will never be able to cover all case of other developers using functions the wrong way.

Comment: @KlausD. true. However, don't you think that having something like `ep = EndProcess()` or `ep = EndProcessWrapper.get_ep()` is easier to use & more common than `with EndProcess as ep`? Especially, when you have more than one resource requiring class that interact in some way. With a `with` statement you would have to nest them, which gets kind of ugly / hard to read pretty fast?!

Comment: daniel451: You don't have to explicitly nest them. It's valid to begin more than one context manage at a time (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)): i.e.: `with x() as a, y() as b, z() as c:` is allowed.

Comment: Also, I agree that wrapping a wrapper isn't Pythonic. The whole point of a context manager is to ensure that the context is "closed" when the following suite of statements finishes execution, even if that's because an exception was thrown. The tradeoff is, yes, one does have to remember to use `with` instead of writing a lot of code yourself that ensures that happens for every conceivable execution path through the block of code. There may also be cases where not using a context manager makes perfect sense. For example, files are context managers in Python—but are often used standalone, too.

Comment: I'll just add my two cents: I agree with everything @martineau and Klaus D. said. avoid nested wrappers as they start getting ugly fast. But beside that, there's no need to wrap the `with` statement. There are somethings the end user is expected to do. If you clearly document how your class should be used, it's up to them to follow it. Sure you add complexity, but I believe what you gain outweighs that. Guaranteed setup and tear down logic.